# Why can't I use collection data in Meteor JS

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to make a simple game. Here's the code:

```
Template.my_player.player = function(){

    var players = Players.find({ userId: Meteor.userId() });

    Session.set("this_x", 5); // WORKS
    Session.set("this_x", players.my_x); // DOESNT WORK

    return players;

};
```

I am trying to find and remember where the player is. Later on, I'm trying to find who else is on the same X and Y sqaure, and it wont work.

```
// ==============
// PLAYERS IN AREA
// ==============
Template.players.players = function(data){

    var my_player = Players.find({ userId: Meteor.userId() });

    var players = Players.find({ my_x: my_player.my_x });

    return players;

};
```

In both cases, I am unable to use the data that I just searched for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `players` is a cursor, use `players.fetch()` to retrieve all the found players as an array (or use `findOne` instead of `find` if you just want to find one player).

Comment: Where would I use players.fetch() - I don't understand where it goes. FindOne gives me no results at all.

Answer (score 0):

That's because

```
var players = Players.find({ userId: Meteor.userId() });
```

returns a cursor. So if you try to do:

```
var players = Players.find({ userId: Meteor.userId() });
console.log(players.my_x); //undefined
```

players.my_x gives you undefined, because you try to access undefined cursor property.

You need to use findOne:

```
var player = Players.findOne({ userId: Meteor.userId() });
if (player) {
    console.log(player.my_x); //logs player position
}
```

The code above will find logged in user. If user is not logged in, player variable will be undefined. Use console.log() for debugging. It's easy.

Comment: This solution works inside my Console - but won't work within the actual program. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to use an IF statement! I had to check to see if the data was there before I could use it. I'm not sure why, but I hope this helps some one!

```
// ==============
// PLAYERS IN AREA
// ==============
Template.players.players = function(){

    var player = Players.findOne({ userId: Meteor.userId() });
    if(player){
        console.log(player.my_x);
        var players = Players.find({ my_x: player.my_x});
    }

    return players;

};
```

Notice if(player){

Once I wrapped my code in this, it magically worked. Boy this is different from PHP...

Comment: There's no magic in this, just reactivity (though indeed, they are tough to tell apart sometimes). Notice that `player` can be null if `findOne` doesn't have the necessary data yet, in which case `player.my_x` would throw an error if it wasn't safeguarded with this `if`.